# Dimension decreases after performing "pyramid_reduce" function. How to fix?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am trying to downscale the image using "scikit-image". However I cannot show the downscaled picture through matplotlib.imshow function because of the dimension. Is there a way to prevent such dimension reduction? I put the script as well.

```
import os, cv2, glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import pyramid_reduce,
plt.style.use('dark_background')

img_path = os.path.join(img_base_path, value[0])
img = io.imread(img_path)
resized = pyramid_reduce(img, downscale=4)
print(resized.shape)
```

img.shape is (240, 240, 3). So what I expect for an output is (60, 60, 3). However what I get is (60, 60, 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read the [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.pyramid_reduce) of the pyramid_reduce function, I notice the parameter `multichannel`:

> **multichannel**: bool,optional
>
> Whether the last axis of the image is to be
>   interpreted as multiple channels or another spatial dimension.

So I would suggest you to set that to **True**, otherwise he is treating your 2D color images as a 3D BW image:

```
resized = pyramid_reduce(img, downscale=4, multichannel=True)
```

Comment: In that case, please accept this as the good answer. This way you show other users that the question is solved, and you also get 2 reputation points :)